# How to use angular modules? (NullInjectorError: No provider for Router)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-module

I'm new to angular modules and I have sliced my (working) application into these seperate modules for start:

```
/app
    /core
    /admin
    /authentication
    /wst
```

All folders have its *.module.ts file, some of them have a *.routing.module.ts, too. At first I would be happy to see my login page that is a component in the authentication module but I got errors only. Right now it says:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterModule -> Router]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterModule -> Router]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!

I have tried to add the Router module everywhere that is related and some other places that is not but still. Why am I getting this error? What is missing?

**/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    CoreModule,
    AuthenticationModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**/app/authentication/authentication.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AuthenticationRoutingModule } from './authentication.routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AuthenticationRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPageComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

**/app/authentication/authentication.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '/login', component: LoginPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove  **`AuthenticationModule`** from providers inside the app.module.ts

Only the services should remain under providers array.

Comment: If I remove AuthenticationModule, the error is: `'app-login-page' is not a known element:` The `app-login-page` component is declared in the AuthenticationModule

Comment: I have removed the `app-login-page` tag from `app.component.html`. Now I don't get any errors but the LoginComponent is not showing up either.

Comment: Again you need to remove coremodule from providers and have it under imports

Comment: I have already removed everything from app.module providers array. It builds now and doesn't throw any error in the browser but LoginComponent is not showing up either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `import` following in your `app module`.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{ path: '', loadChildren: 'path/to/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule ' }])
```

Dont forget to change `path/to` to your actual path

Comment: Didn't help. ng build now says: `ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AuthenticationModule '.`

Answer (score 0):

I had several problems with my code, including the ones I got as solutions. One of them was that somehow I removed the  tag in my app.component.html. Working modules:

**/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    CoreModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule' }
    ]),
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**/app/authentication/authentication.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { routing } from './authentication.routing';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    routing
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPageComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

**/app/authentication/authentication.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginPageComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the following changes -

### AuthenticationRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '/login', component: LoginPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes), //<-- change it to Root if it is parent routing.
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationRoutingModule { }
```

### AppModule

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    CoreModule,
    AuthenticationModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```